# Proving $\{w:f_n(w)\text{is not converge to }f(w)\}=\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty\{w:|f_n(w)-f(w)|\geq \dfrac{1}{k}\}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-writing

> $f_n,f$ is real function, please prove:
> $$\{w:f_n(w)\text{is not converge to }f(w)\}=\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty\{w:|f_n(w)-f(w)|\geq \dfrac{1}{k}\}$$

I know definition of function convergence,and I can understand the equation that need to be proven,but how can I prove it with formal mathematical language?

Comment: It's just by defintion ;-) $f_n(\omega )$ doesn't converges to $f(\omega )$ $\iff$ $$\exists k\in\mathbb N:\forall N\in \mathbb N,\exists n_N\geq N: |f_{n_N}(\omega )-f(\omega )|\geq \frac{1}{k}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's just do an inclusion proof. I'll let the set on the left be denoted by $A$ and the set on the right will be denoted by $B$.

1. $B \subseteq A$.

Suppose that $w \in B$. Now, the idea is to go through each union and intersection using the definition. So:
$$w \in B \implies (\exists k \in \mathbb{N}: w \in \bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} \{w: |f_n(w)-f(w)| \geq \frac{1}{k}\})$$

We go through the next symbol:
$$w \in B \implies (\exists k \in \mathbb{N}: \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: w \in \bigcup_{n = N}^{\infty} \{w: |f_n(w)-f(w)| \geq \frac{1}{k} \})$$
Finally, we have that:
$$w \in B \implies (\exists k \in \mathbb{N}: \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n \geq N: |f_n(w)-f(w)| \geq \frac{1}{k})$$
Next, let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{k}$. Then, the right-hand side above is just the negation of the definition of "$f_n(w)$ converges to $f(w)$". So, it follows that $w \in A$.

2. $A \subseteq B$.

Let $w \in A$. Then, $f_n(w)$ does not converge to $f(w)$. By definition:
$$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n \geq N: |f_n(w)-f(w)| \geq \epsilon$$
Select a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then, the above implies that:
$$\exists k \in \mathbb{N}: \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n \geq N: |f_n(w)-f(w)| \geq \frac{1}{k}$$
But now, you can see that this actually just corresponds to $w$ being an element of $B$. So, we're done. $\Box$